# Using Javascript to build a domain white list validator

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, subdomain

i'm building a domain restriction function for my website by JAVASCRIPT. More detail, when any another site framing to my web page(put my web page to their iframe), i want to detect them and check it exist in a white list domain or not.
Example:
white list domain array:

```
var whiteDomainList = ["partner1.com", "*.partner2.com"];
```

`*.partner2.com` means that `partner2.com` or subdomain of `partner2.com` are allowed.

And an unknown website  put a my web page to their iframe.

```
 <iframe src="http://mywebsite.com" width="100%" height="1000px"></iframe>
```

I really detected the framing site by `document.referrer` but i still stuck at checking white list domain problem. Can you help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you can maintain the white-list in an array and then check if the result of `document.referrer` exists in the array.

Comment: my problem is how to check it, use regex or somthing more simple? The difficult is check the domain in "*.domain.com"